# Limit of 100 simultaneous connections in Database Realtime with Blaze plan

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The free plan has a limit of 100 connections. Now, if I buy the Blaze plan, I exceed the free connection limit, but not storage, or downloads, will they charge me something? because in the characteristics of this plan it says that it has 200,000 simultaneous connections, but you do not have to pay, instead in storage and downloads if necessary.

Could you get me out of doubt, please?
Thank you

Comment: What does the word "exedo" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebase here*

When you upgrade to the paid plan on your Firebase project, you are only charged for the storage and bandwidth for Realtime Database. There is no charge for the number of concurrent users.

So it is possible to upgrade to the paid plan, get many more concurrent users, and not pay anything.